# return a Comma separated string in Parent Child relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a I have a database structure that looks like this.

```
Course
     CourseID-------------
     Name                 |     
                          |    
MultiCourse               |     
      MultiCourseID---------------------------
      MultiCourseName     |                   |
                          |                   | 
MultiCourseDetail         |                   |
      MultiCourseDetailID |                   |
      MultiCourseID       |                   |
      CourseID-------------                   |    
                                              |     
StudentRegistration                           |    
      StudentRegistrationID                   |    
      StudentName                             |    
                                              |    
StudentRegistrationCourse                     |    
      StudentRegistrationCourseID             |    
      StudentRegistrationID                   |     
      MultiCourseID---------------------------
```

I want to list all the Course (seperated by commas) taken by the student during registration.I have tried the following way but its giving me list of courses instead of courses seperated by commas

```
 List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> _dTableReg = new List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> ();
 _dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
              .AsEnumerable()
              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Id)
              .Select(r => new 
               {                    
                   SoftwareUsed = r.StudentRegistrationCourses
                                 .Select(c => c.MultiCourse.MultiCourseDetails
                                 .Select(mc => mc.Course.Name).Aggregate((m, n) => m + "," + n)).ToList()
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `Aggregate` too early, if you change the first `Select` to a `SelectMany` then you should be able to move the Aggregate to after the `ToList` and get the results you are looking for. In fact, once this change has been made, the `ToList` isn't even needed anymore. Here is what it would look like:

```
List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> _dTableReg = new List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> ();
 _dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
              .AsEnumerable()
              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Id)
              .Select(r => new 
               {                    
                   SoftwareUsed = r.StudentRegistrationCourses
                                 .SelectMany(c => c.MultiCourse.MultiCourseDetails
                                 .Select(mc => mc.Course.Name)).Aggregate((m, n) => m + "," + n)
                }
```

As mentioned in the comment below, `Aggregate` doesn't work with empty collections so to work around this if you need to support empty collections, use `string.Join` like this:

```
List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> _dTableReg = new List<RegistraionVM.RegDataTable> ();
 _dTableReg = _db.StudentRegistrations
              .AsEnumerable()
              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Id)
              .Select(r => new 
               {                    
                   SoftwareUsed = string.Join(",", r.StudentRegistrationCourses
                                 .SelectMany(c => c.MultiCourse.MultiCourseDetails
                                 .Select(mc => mc.Course.Name)))
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate.But here I am getting `System.Invalid Exception` and the message is `sequence contains no elements`.

Comment: You can't use `Aggregate` if there aren't any elements for one of the entries. Instead, you could use string.Join. Like this: `SoftwareUsed = string.Join(",", r.StudentRegistrationCourses.SelectMany(c => c.MultiCourse.MultiCourseDetails.Select(mc => mc.Course.Name)))`

Comment: Thanks mate it worked wonderfully well :) and your are right there was an element with null entry (which I was not noticed) while using aggregate function and thats why error came earlier.